# AuthService with AngularJS not work

Tags: angularjs

Hi friends i am new with angular js. 
i try to create login and register with angular js.
i used this tutorials for authentication.[Click here](https://medium.com/@mattlanham/authentication-with-angularjs-4e927af3a15f)

i got [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=AuthServiceProvider%20%3C-%20AuthService) error i don't know why i think i forgot to include any authentication js file.

please how to resolve this error.

Comment: Can you paste your code? or create a jsfiddle/plunkr for the same?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using $routeProvider for your angular app. but in your example angular app is using $stateProvider.so you have to install angular-ui-router.js and give reference to it to the index.html . 
and also you have to put dependency 'ui.router' in to app.js

Answer (score 0):

Stop the Javascript based authentication and opt for a **token based approach** using server-side language like PHP coupled with AJAX.